# Privacy problem of the Azur pop mail server at the badly honest webmaster

Tags: email, server, privacy, pop3, mail-server

A webmaster has installed a POP3 mail server on Azure for a Compagny, the customer complains of not having his mails synchronized, I asked this webmaster why not have left the default server integrated with the domain name provider LWS (.com) he simply replied that this mail server was linked to the website hosted on its own server and not at LWS.

The question I ask myself, what is the point and with a POP configuration that does not suit the proper functioning of the company's emails.

Does this webmaster have access to all company emails? Is there a privacy issue or fraud?

Answer (score 0):

Mail server admins generally *do* have full access to all messages stored on the server. The question is really one of trust: who do you trust more: LWS or this other person?

If the answer is neither, you should be running your own mail server.

Also, nobody should be using POP3 for collecting email any more; IMAP is vastly superior.